# Playing particles multiple times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

So I'm pretty sure there is a simple answer to this, but I don't know it or really what to look for. I have some code that is designed so that, when the player holds down the mouse button, a particle emitter sprays particles where they are facing, and when they stop holding it down, it stops spraying. So far, that is working, except, if they make a burst of particles, stop clicking, then try to click again, no new particles will be created until the first cloud stops existing. I'm not sure if I need to change some settings or not. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton (0) && scoreTrack.sprayBottles > 0) {
        if(!sprayEffect.GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ().isPlaying) 
            sprayEffect.GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ().Play ();
}
else if (!Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
        if(sprayEffect.GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ().isPlaying)
            sprayEffect.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Stop();

}
```

What the settings look like:

[image: The current settings]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem may be not setting enableEmission according to [this question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/551466/how-play-and-stop-a-particlesystem-through-scripti.html):

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton (0) && scoreTrack.sprayBottles > 0) {
        if(!sprayEffect.GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ().isPlaying){ 
            sprayEffect.GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ().Play ();
            sprayEffect.GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ().enableEmission=true;
        }
}
else if (!Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
        if(sprayEffect.GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ().isPlaying){
            sprayEffect.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Stop();
            sprayEffect.GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ().enableEmission=false;
        }

}
```

I don't have unity in front of me, so I don't know for sure that this will fix things.

Comment: Well it IS emitting particles, just it seems it can't emit any more until the ones first emitted run through their lifespan.

Comment: Which seems to imply that `.Stop()` isn't working for some reason. Is there ever a time when you click the mouse and `sprayEffect...isPlaying()` is true?

Comment: Yes. When I first click it, it works, and it makes some particles. But when I stop clicking, I it will not play again until every particle has gone away.